# How to get contents of Test Explorer window in Visual Studio programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, vs-extensibility

I am developing my first add-in for VS 2012. I need to programmatically find which test is selected by user from Test Explorer window.

How do i do that?

Any pointers and help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question correctly,but May be this will help you ,
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173496/How-to-Create-a-Visual-Studio-Add-in-that-Launches

Comment: Thanks, but i have all wired up till the point i can right click on a test in test explorer window and my command shows up. I can click on it and do further execution. What i am looking for is, how do i know programatically know which test i have clicked so that in exec i can use that info.